# Geth 'sendTransaction' not working for some transactions while making much transactions in a loop

Tags: p2p, blockchain, ethereum

We are making 200 transactions in a loop for sending ether from one address to another address, all transaction should execute and return either success or fail.

But Some transactions are not executing i.e. we are not getting any results for those transactions neither success nor fail.

Steps to reproduce the behavior

Make 200 transactions in a loop to send ether from one address to another address

```
eth.sendTransaction({
from: privateWeb3.eth.coinbase,
to: result,
value: privateWeb3.toWei(2, 'ether')
}
```

check total no of results.
Total no of results will be less than total no. of transactions given

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of this is duplicated nonces. Each transaction includes a consecutive increasing number called nonce. If you generate transactions too fast and geth didn't update fast enough, it will reuse the last one. So you will generate two transaction with the same nonce, in such case geth will reject one.

Comment: How can we overcome this problem, then ?

Comment: One posibility is to read the nonce at the beginning and the explicitely set that value for each of the following transactions. For example is the nonce is 29, then you will generate transaction with nonces 29, 30, 31,..., 128.